# Draw a ball in a Panel and move the ball using mouseDragged

Tags: java, graphics, awt, java-2d

I am practicing to draw a ball in the Panel and show the ball's coordinate when the ball is dragged.

This is my first time to practice a drawing exercise(?)

This is my code.

```
import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;

public class MovingBall extends Frame {
Panel ballPanel = new Panel();
Label ballLabel = new Label();
Panel coordinatePanel = new Panel();
Label coordinateLabel = new Label();
int x0=0,y0 =0, x=20,y=30;
int nowX, nowY;
Label nowXcoordinateLabel = new Label("Now X :"+nowX);
Label nowYcoordinateLabel = new Label("Now Y :"+nowY);
MovingBall(){
    setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
    ballPanel.add(ballLabel); coordinatePanel.add(coordinateLabel);

    add(ballPanel);
    add(coordinatePanel);
    ballPanel.setBackground(Color.white);

    coordinatePanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    nowXcoordinateLabel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    nowYcoordinateLabel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    coordinatePanel.add(nowXcoordinateLabel);
    coordinatePanel.add(nowYcoordinateLabel);
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(400,400);

    MouseMotionListener ml = new MouseMotionAdapter(){
   public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
      Point p = new Point();
      nowX = (int) p.getX();
      nowY = (int) p.getY();
  }  
};
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
        dispose();
     }
    }
   );
  }
   public void paintComponent(Graphics2D gg){
   // super.paintComponents(gg);
    ballPanel.paintComponents(gg);
    gg.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    gg.fillOval(x0, y0, 10, 10);

}



public static void main(String[]arg){
    MovingBall mb = new MovingBall();
}
}
```

I have two problems

1. I used `fillOval` and `paintComponent` to draw and display a ball but I don't see that on the screen. Why?
2. Any idea how to move the ball if I want to move that using `mouseDragged`? Do I need some thread?

Comment: You tagged this as a Swing question so you should be using Swing components, not AWT components. Swing components start with a `"J"` (JButton, JPanel...); Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting]() for the basics of painting. The working code shows how to change the location of a square on a mouse event. Modify the code you handle mouseDragged.

Comment: AWT `Frame` doesn't have a `paintComponent` method, add `@Override` to the method, it will create a compiler error.  This also, not how you should be doing custom painting, the `ballPanel` should be doing the painitng, not the frame. People stopped using AWT over 10 years ago, you'd get a better response using Swing or Java FX

Comment: I know my mouseDragged is wrong, but I did that just to check if my Label is working or not.

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks for nice advice! But I have to learn awt because I will have java test next week. . :(

Comment: @MadProgrammer what do you mean  "the ballPanel should be doing the painitng, not the frame."? Could you explain me that little bit more?

Comment: Where is your Swing code?

Comment: @CoderACJHP hmm.. I edited the tag. Are you still seeing swing in tags?

Comment: @ProgramLover's Yes my application not refreshed the question.Sorry about this.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with

- `Frame` doesn't have a `paintComponent` method, so nothing is ever going to call it.
- Even if it did, position `0x0` would paint the circle under the frame's borders, so you wouldn't see it
- You should be getting the `Point` from the `MouseEvent`, not from the new `Point` object you've created
- It's not the responsibility of the frame to manage the mouse dragged or painting, the frame is responsible for providing the initial container onto which everything else added

From that, you should move the functionality of the painting and mouse dragged management to it's own class. This provides you with two things, first, a surface onto which you can paint, and which will contained within the frame borders and the mouse events will automatically be converted to the panels context (`0x0` will be the top left corner of the panel)

This raises the question about how to update the labels.  Well, you could take a leaf from the AWT API and use a simple observer pattern to generate events when the coordinates are changed, for example

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.Panel;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.EventObject;
import java.util.List;

public class MovingBall extends Frame {

    BallPane ballPanel = new BallPane();
    Label ballLabel = new Label();
    int x0 = 0, y0 = 0, x = 20, y = 30;
    int nowX, nowY;
    Label nowXcoordinateLabel = new Label("Now X :" + nowX);
    Label nowYcoordinateLabel = new Label("Now Y :" + nowY);

    MovingBall() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        ballPanel.add(ballLabel);

        add(ballPanel);
        ballPanel.setBackground(Color.white);

        nowXcoordinateLabel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        nowYcoordinateLabel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(400, 400);
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                dispose();
            }
        });

        Panel coordinates = new Panel(new FlowLayout());
        coordinates.add(nowXcoordinateLabel);
        coordinates.add(nowYcoordinateLabel);
        coordinates.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        add(coordinates, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        ballPanel.addCoordinateListene(new CoordinateListener() {
            @Override
            public void coordinatesChanged(CoordinateEvent evt) {
                nowXcoordinateLabel.setText("Now X: " + evt.getCoordinate().getX());
                nowYcoordinateLabel.setText("Now X: " + evt.getCoordinate().getY());
                revalidate();
                repaint();
            }
        });

    }

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        MovingBall mb = new MovingBall();
    }

    public class CoordinateEvent extends EventObject {
        private final Point p;

        public CoordinateEvent(Object source, Point p) {
            super(source);
            this.p = p;
        }

        public Point getCoordinate() {
            return p;
        }
    }

    public interface CoordinateListener {
        public void coordinatesChanged(CoordinateEvent evt);
    }

    public class BallPane extends Panel {

        int x0 = 0, y0 = 0, x = 20, y = 30;
        private List<CoordinateListener> coordinateListeners;

        public BallPane() {
            MouseMotionListener ml = new MouseMotionAdapter() {
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                    x0 = (int) e.getX();
                    y0 = (int) e.getY();
                    fireCoordinateChange(new Point(e.getPoint()));
                    repaint();
                }
            };
            addMouseMotionListener(ml);
            coordinateListeners = new ArrayList<>(5);
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.fillOval(x0, y0, 10, 10);
        }

        public void addCoordinateListene(CoordinateListener listener) {
            coordinateListeners.add(listener);
        }

        public void removeCoordinateListene(CoordinateListener listener) {
            coordinateListeners.remove(listener);
        }

        protected void fireCoordinateChange(Point p) {
            CoordinateEvent evt = new CoordinateEvent(this, p);
            for (CoordinateListener listener : coordinateListeners) {
                listener.coordinatesChanged(evt);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your class extending `Panel` and make it ready to drawing with overriding `paint` method and add the `MouseMotionListener` to listining your panel.Get X and Y coordinates for using in `paint` method, at last add your drawing panel to `Frame`.

Simple code : **UPDATED**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.Panel;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

public class TestClass extends Panel {


        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        Panel ballPanel = new Panel();
        Label ballLabel = new Label();
        Panel coordinatePanel = new Panel();
        Label coordinateLabel = new Label();
        int nowX, nowY;
        Label nowXcoordinateLabel = new Label("Now X :");
        Label nowYcoordinateLabel = new Label("Now Y :");

        TestClass() {

            coordinatePanel.add(coordinateLabel);
            nowXcoordinateLabel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            nowYcoordinateLabel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            nowXcoordinateLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 25));
            nowYcoordinateLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 25));
            coordinatePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 30));
            coordinatePanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            coordinatePanel.add(nowXcoordinateLabel);
            coordinatePanel.add(nowYcoordinateLabel);

            MouseAdapter ml = new MouseAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                    nowXcoordinateLabel.setText("Now X :" + e.getX());
                    nowYcoordinateLabel.setText("Now Y :" + e.getY());
                    nowX = e.getX();
                    nowY = e.getY();
                    repaint();
                    super.mouseMoved(e);
                }

            };


            setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            addMouseMotionListener(ml);
            setVisible(true);
            setSize(400, 400);
        }


        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D gg = (Graphics2D) g;
            gg.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            gg.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            gg.fillOval(nowX, nowY, 20, 20);

        }

        public static void main(String[] arg) {
            TestClass mb = new TestClass();
            Frame frame = new Frame("Test drawing");
            frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {


                @Override
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                     frame.dispose();
                    super.windowClosing(e);
                }


            });
            frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
            frame.add(mb);
            frame.add(mb.coordinatePanel);
            frame.setSize(800, 600);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }


}
```

Comment: While I would certain recommend Swing over AWT the OP has stated on at least two occasions that *'I have to learn awt because I will have java test next week"* - you're also breaking the paint chain, which could generate unwanted paint artifacts

Answer (score 0):

To get the position of the mouse instead of:

```
nowX = (int) p.getX();
```

Write this:

```
nowX = (int) e.getX();
```

You also need to redraw the oval every time the user triggers a Mouse Drag event

Comment: Yeah I know that I just did that to check if my Label is working. but I have tried your suggestion (0,0,-10,-10) but that does not work

Comment: `(0,0,-10,-10)` - `Graphics` doesn't support negative width/heights, positioning the object at `0x0` when using the `Frame` as the canvas would place the object under the frame borders, but all in all, that's not the initial problem

Comment: @ProgramLover
Try adding a color before filloval with gg.setColor(Color.orange);

Comment: @MaurizioRicci It is